# jQuery / Javascript code check, if not undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined

Is this code good?

```
var wlocation = $(this).closest('.myclass').find('li a').attr('href');
if (wlocation.prop !== undefined) { window.location = wlocation; }
```

or should I do

```
var wlocation = $(this).closest('.myclass').find('li a').attr('href');
if (wlocation.prop !== "undefined") { window.location = wlocation; }
```

Answer (score 104, accepted):

I like this:

```
if (wlocation !== undefined)
```

But if you prefer the second way wouldn't be as you posted. It would be:

```
if (typeof wlocation  !== "undefined")
```

Comment: wlocation is just a string (the value of the href attribute) so it has not any prop property...

Answer (score 14):

I generally like the shorthand version:

```
if (!!wlocation) { window.location = wlocation; }
```

Comment: +1 Really nice, I didn't knew the `!!` command for `not-undefined`.

Comment: @MichelAyres `!!` is not a special *operator* or "not undefined"... it is basically two not operators after each other, eg; `!!undefined => not (not undefined) => not (true) => false`

Answer (score 4):

[$.fn.attr(attributeName)](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr1) returns the attribute value as string, or `undefined` when the attribute is not present.

Since `""`, and `undefined` are both *falsy* (evaluates to false when coerced to boolean) values in JavaScript, in this case I would write the check as below:

```
if (wlocation) { ... }
```